# Distance across multiple GPS points

Tags: r, gps, distance

I'm relatively new to R.
I'm working on creating a tortuosity index of a line along GPS points but to work this out I'm trying to calculate the distance between the point n and the n+10 point for my latitude and longitude data.

I have already used distanceTrack to calculate the distance between every point in series:

```
lat<-data$Latitude
long<-data$Longitude

distanceTrack(lat,long)
```

But I wonder if there is an alternative for doing this over 10 steps?

I tried using another method that used sp package and spDistsN1 to get distances between successive points:

```
coordinates(gpsdat)<-~Longitude+Latitude 
proj4string(gpsdat)<-CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

dist<-sapply(seq_along(gpsdat[-1,]), function(i)
        spDistsN1(pts=gpsdat[i,],pt=gpsdat[i+1,],longlat=TRUE))
```

I thought I might be able to simply change some of the script so it was:

```
 dist<-sapply(seq_along(gpsdat[-1,]), function(i)
            spDistsN1(pts=gpsdat[i,],pt=gpsdat[i+10,],longlat=TRUE))
```

But this change returns that my subscript is out of bounds. 
I wonder if anyone might have an idea of how to progress with this? 
Thank you for any help you can offer!

Comment: Of course it goes out of bounds. What happens when it gets the the (`nrow(gpsdat)`-5)th row?

Comment: Hi Michael - I'm not sure how I would increase the bounds though? I'm sorry if this is a silly question but I'm working with something I'm still learning and I'd really appreciate an explanation?

Comment: You can't. You need to restrict your loop so that it only operates on `nrow`-10 rows instead of all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this without using an apply or loop structure with `data.table` and `geosphere`.

For that we **shift** the lat/lon rows by 5 in my example, **filter** out those, that dont have NA values, **calculate** the distance per row and **reassign** the distance to the original data.table. You can vary the amount of shifts to your desire.

My example also groups by L1, as it assumes different Line-Ids. You can adapt the grouping column or just omit it.

```
library(data.table)
library(geosphere)

## Data
points = data.table(
  id = 1:20,
  lon = seq(11, 30, 1),
  lat = seq(51, 70, 1),
  L1 = rep(seq(1,2,1), each=10)
)

## Shift Rows
points[, c("next_id", "next_lon", "next_lat") := data.table::shift(.SD, 5, NA, "lead"), 
        .SDcols=c("id","lon","lat"), by = L1];

## Filter NA values
points_not_NA = points[!is.na(points$next_lon),]

## Get Distance
distRes <- distCosine(as.matrix(points_not_NA[,c("lon","lat")]), 
                      as.matrix(points_not_NA[,c("next_lon","next_lat")]))

## Assign initial value for distance
points$dist <- 0

## Assign resulting distance to filtered table
points[!is.na(points$next_lon),]$dist <- distRes

points
```

> ```
> > points
>     id lon lat L1 next_id next_lon next_lat        dist
>  1:  1  11  51  1       6       16       56 647237.8260
>  2:  2  12  52  1       7       17       57 643248.9003
>  3:  3  13  53  1       8       18       58 639283.2756
>  4:  4  14  54  1       9       19       59 635346.2618
>  5:  5  15  55  1      10       20       60 631443.2317
>  6:  6  16  56  1      NA       NA       NA      0.0000
>  7:  7  17  57  1      NA       NA       NA      0.0000
>  8:  8  18  58  1      NA       NA       NA      0.0000
>  9:  9  19  59  1      NA       NA       NA      0.0000
> 10: 10  20  60  1      NA       NA       NA      0.0000
> 11: 11  21  61  2      16       26       66 609045.7607
> 12: 12  22  62  2      17       27       67 605534.8132
> 13: 13  23  63  2      18       28       68 602102.1704
> 14: 14  24  64  2      19       29       69 598753.3917
> 15: 15  25  65  2      20       30       70 595494.0003
> 16: 16  26  66  2      NA       NA       NA      0.0000
> 17: 17  27  67  2      NA       NA       NA      0.0000
> 18: 18  28  68  2      NA       NA       NA      0.0000
> 19: 19  29  69  2      NA       NA       NA      0.0000
> 20: 20  30  70  2      NA       NA       NA      0.0000
> ```